# Django Memcached displaying wrong logged in user

Tags: django, memcached

I have an internal application that has at any one time 20-100 logged in users. In an attempt to help speed up the delivery of some views I added Memcached and added template level caching (fragment) for some static views.

After a few minutes of memcached being turned on you will see a different user being displayed in the "Logged in as" display in the header. Refreshing the page will usually display a different user as if the caching is mixing up the sessions?

[image]

My Middleware.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
```

)

```
CACHES = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
    'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
}
```

}

Here is an example of the caching tag I use on a few of the templates:

```
{% load cache %}
{% cache 500 right_sidebar %}
<aside class="user-menu no-print">
  <div class="tabs-offcanvas">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
      <li class="active"><a href="#userbar-one" data-toggle="tab">Main</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#userbar-two" data-toggle="tab">ToDo</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="userbar-one" class="tab-pane active">
        <div class="main-info">
          <div class="user-img">{% include "_tag_avatar.html" %}
          </div>
          <h1>{{ request.user.first_name }}&nbsp;{{ request.user.last_name }}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="list-group"><a href="/accounts/profile/?id={{request.user.id}}" class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-user">&nbsp;Profile</i></a><a href="/accounts/lock/" data-toggle="modal" class="list-group-item lockme"><i class="fa fa-lock">&nbsp;Lock</i></a><a href="/accounts/logout/" data-toggle="modal" class="list-group-item logout"><i class="fa fa-power-off">&nbsp;Sign Out</i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
....
```

I did not implement any caching on views, just template level caching for those static his use templates. I also DID NOT cache the header HTML.

Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your templates, you are clearly caching the sidebar that contains details of the logged in user. It is not surprising that a later visitor to the site will see the cached fragment from an earlier, different user.

```
{% load cache %}
{% cache 500 right_sidebar %}
...
<h1>{{ request.user.first_name }}&nbsp;{{ request.user.last_name }}</h1>
...
{% endcache %}
```

The simplest fix is to remove the cache tag from this block. Alternatively, the docs suggest that you can include the username when using the cache tag and cache per-user. You'll have fewer 'cache hits' when you do this, so only do it for blocks that contain user details.

```
{% load cache %}
{% cache 500 right_sidebar request.user.username %}
...
<h1>{{ request.user.first_name }}&nbsp;{{ request.user.last_name }}</h1>
...
{% endcache %}
```